# How do I convert a list in quotes ( '[1,2,3]' ) to a proper list ( [1,2,3] ) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is very fundamental. All I want to know is if there is a function to perform the task without appending to a new list.

I tried using loop but it will become a little complex for cases like...
'[1,2,3],[4,5,6]'

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval(your_string)`. Similar questions have been asked several times before (I am just too lazy to hunt for them now to mark as duplicate).

Comment: how did you get this string with list ? if it is JSON data then you can use `json` module. If you created it using `print(list)` or write(list) then maybe you should display/write it in different way or convert to something more useful.

Comment: I am picking data from excel. And the data is a list of lists.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("'|\[|\]")
new_list = re.sub(regex, "", '[1,2,3],[4,5,6]')
```

I'm sure that you can find a wiser way.

Answer (score -1):

```
In [1]: a = '[1,2,3],[4,5,6]'                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: import ast                                                                                                                                                      

In [3]: ast.literal_eval(a)                                                                                                                                             
Out[3]: ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

For ref : [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)